# Vertical aligning a div inside ion-col - IONIC 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework

In my IONIC 4 application I am trying to `vertical-align` a `div` inside an `ion-row` / `ion-col` element. This kinda works but the second `ion-col`, which has an `ion-icon` inside it, messes up the height of the row (which is visible by it's borders).

So I have the following `html` setup (only showing the bit that matters):

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-row class="top-icons ion-text-center">
    <ion-col class="ion-padding">
      <div class="element-color" [style.backgroundColor]="getColorString(el)"></div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="ion-padding">
      <ion-icon name="warning" color="danger" *ngIf="el.IsCcp"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="cog" *ngIf="!el.IsCcp"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    .. Other stuff
```

**The sccs of the html:**

```
.top-icons > ion-col {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--ion-color-lightGray);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--ion-color-lightGray);

    .element-color {
      width: 22px;
      height: 22px;
      border-radius: 7px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    ion-icon {
      font-size: 1.7em;
      padding-top: 2px;
    }

    &:first-child {
      border-right: 1px solid var(--ion-color-lightGray);
    }
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

p {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

Which results in the following, the problem however is that the `div` is not `vertical-aligned` in the ion-col element, while the `ion-icon` is:

[image]

When taking a closer look it gets obvious that the `div` is not getting vertically aligned in the `ion-col`:

[image]

I thought I could fix this with the IONIC css utility `ion-align-items-center` on the `ion-row`:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row class="top-icons ion-text-center ion-align-items-center">
    <ion-col class="ion-padding">
        <div class="element-color" [style.backgroundColor]="getColorString(el)"></div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="ion-padding">
      <ion-icon name="warning" color="danger" *ngIf="el.IsCcp"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="cog" *ngIf="!el.IsCcp"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

    .. Other stuff
```

Which results in the following, but unfortunately introduces a new problem:

[image]

So now the div is vertical aligned but the ion-col itself has been moved in comparison to the other ion-col:

[image]

This can be fixed by changing the `font-size` of the `ion-icon` back to its original font but this makes the icon way to small.. :

[image]

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: oh man;) sorry just feel your pain and do not have a solution yet. I think vertical/horizontal alignments were among the toughest issues to understand;)